# Case update flow through external email works only on debug

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, email2case

I have a flow that is supposed to do the following: Whenever a new email is received for an existing case, the owner of the case should change. The original case is assigned to a queue the first time (standard field) and in another user-lookup field a case responsible user is selected.

If the case now ends up in a certain queue and a new email is received for it, **the case owner should change to the case responsible (and the status should go back to open regardless).**
When debugging the flow everything works. (Meaning a previously send email switch the case owner to the case responsible owner).
If it is activated and I test the whole thing with an external email it does not work.

Can anyone see why?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards
Alex
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to be clear about the problem.  What should it be doing? What isn't it doing? When you say it doesn't work, you need to actually tell us the problem

Answer (score 1):

"it does not work" is very hard to understand what the problem is, but I'll have a stab anyway.

You `Case_geschlossen` criteria is not doing what you think it's doing.  The `(3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8)` part will *always* be true.

Think about it.  If the record type is Onboarding_personProflier, it's obviously not Onboarding_Persy.

Perhaps change this logic to be AND instead of OR.

Comment: You´re right. Sorry. It should change the owner to the responsible user when it is in a dedicated queue. Otherwise leave the user untouched. But this is a "universal" flow. Meaning whenever an incoming email is created the case should go back to open. So the service rep sees that something is new. If I change it to AND it will never work as these 3 OR 4 are different queues which are case owner. And these should be excluded from reopening.